# Different inputs for different processes in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Please bear with me as this is a bit of a contrived example of my real application. Suppose I have a list of numbers and I wanted to add a single number to each number in the list using multiple (2) processes. I can do something like this:

```
import multiprocessing
my_list = list(range(100))
my_number = 5
data_line = [{'list_num': i, 'my_num': my_number} for i in my_list]

def worker(data):
    return data['list_num'] + data['my_num']

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)
pool_output = pool.map(worker, data_line)
pool.close() 
pool.join()
```

Now however, there's a wrinkle to my problem. Suppose that I wanted to alternate adding two numbers (instead of just adding one). So around half the time, I want to add `my_number1` and the other half of the time I want to add `my_number2`. It doesn't matter which number gets added to which item on the list. However, the one requirement is that I don't want to be adding the same number simultaneously at the same time across the different processes. What this boils down to essentially (I think) is that I want to use the first number on Process 1 and the second number on Process 2 exclusively so that the processes are never simultaneously adding the same number. So something like:

```
my_num1 = 5
my_num2 = 100
data_line = [{'list_num': i, 'my_num1': my_num1, 'my_num2': my_num2} for i in my_list]
def worker(data):
    # if in Process 1:
    return data['list_num'] + data['my_num1']
    # if in Process 2:
    return data['list_num'] + data['my_num2']
    # and so forth
```

Is there an easy way to specify specific inputs per process? Is there another way to think about this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`multiprocessing.Pool` allows to execute an initializer function which is going to be executed before the actual given function will be run.

You can use it altogether with a global variable to allow your function to understand in which process is running.

You probably want to control the initial number the processes will get. You can use a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) to notify to the processes which number to pick up.

This solution is not optimal but it works.

```
import multiprocessing


process_number = None


def initializer(queue):
    global process_number

    process_number = queue.get()  # atomic get the process index


def function(value):
    print "I'm process %s" % process_number

    return value[process_number]


def main():
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    for index in range(multiprocessing.cpu_count()):
        queue.put(index)

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=initializer, initargs=[queue])

    tasks = [{0: 'Process-0', 1: 'Process-1', 2: 'Process-2'}, ...]

    print(pool.map(function, tasks))
```

My PC is a dual core, as you can see only Process-0 and Process-1 are processed.

```
I'm process 0
I'm process 0
I'm process 1
I'm process 0
I'm process 1
...
['Process-0', 'Process-0', 'Process-1', 'Process-0', ... ]
```